# D3: Two similar SVG sized pictures scalling

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, inkscape

I create two SVG icons for my project ad now trying to insert on my page. All goes fine, but there problem with images scalling. They are made in incscape from images of same size, but when i insert them in page i get this:

[image]

I add lines to show what going one. One of images is taller then other.

Here code of blocks i use:

```
<g transform="translate(0.36859130859375,0)">
<rect width="200" height="110" fill="#EBDEE9" x="735" y="258" style="cursor: pointer;"></rect>
<image xlink:href="/media/com_myrod/images/woman-icon.svg" width="100" height="100" x="725" y="263"></image>
<text font-size="16px" fill="black" class="rod-fname-text" x="820" y="283" style="cursor: pointer;"></text>
<text font-size="16px" fill="black" class="rod-fname-text" x="820" y="301" style="cursor: pointer;"></text><text font-size="16px" fill="black" class="rod-fname-text" x="820" y="319" style="cursor: pointer;"></text>
<text font-size="16px" fill="black" class="rod-fname-text" x="820" y="337" style="cursor: pointer;"></text><text font-size="16px" fill="black" class="rod-fname-text" x="820" y="351" style="cursor: pointer;"></text>
</g>
```

Other picture have same code, but URL of icon differs.

here svg files:

woman:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg836"
   sodipodi:docname="woman-icon.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06)">
  <defs
     id="defs830" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-36.360817"
     inkscape:cy="101.5839"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata833">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:0.48401597"
       d="m 60.712789,275.27775 -3.790372,-0.37549 c -2.084698,-0.20652 -7.283975,-0.91204 -11.553924,-1.56781 -4.269963,-0.65577 -10.032395,-1.52294 -12.805414,-1.92702 -2.773005,-0.4041 -8.590237,-1.66064 -12.92718,-2.79235 C 10.4919,266.22901 9.9072264,265.82556 8.3966104,260.8597 6.3669354,254.18754 5.3639364,248.12322 5.0676134,240.73194 3.901584,211.64823 17.937067,183.24261 37.887745,174.30911 44.743584,171.2392 47.958746,170.59 57.563158,170.33622 l 8.650123,-0.22857 0.298706,4.10227 c 1.025701,14.08613 11.490456,26.79405 26.275905,31.90827 4.163278,1.44007 4.579118,1.48995 12.419828,1.48995 7.84073,0 8.25657,-0.0499 12.41985,-1.48995 14.76057,-5.10562 25.25042,-17.82524 26.27215,-31.85667 l 0.29495,-4.05069 h 7.07672 c 11.29853,0 18.64631,1.97683 26.66197,7.17305 21.99739,14.26004 32.4475,48.84701 24.32282,80.50183 -1.58658,6.1815 -3.02803,8.71506 -5.50486,9.67553 -7.07287,2.74273 -36.87123,7.33728 -57.68068,8.8937 -24.09799,-0.0218 -58.043765,1.83211 -78.357851,-1.17719 z M 94.637114,153.73797 c -1.892886,-0.36896 -4.658448,-0.90695 -6.145708,-1.19555 -3.773941,-0.73231 -10.823821,-3.47615 -15.487189,-6.02768 -16.036227,-8.77411 -26.838543,-22.76785 -29.985178,-38.84395 -1.131453,-5.78063 -0.985995,-9.454717 0.485765,-12.269539 0.898278,-1.718002 1.229136,-3.107832 1.229136,-5.163183 0,-9.05414 4.2599,-21.321907 10.663241,-30.708305 3.018013,-4.423972 12.166081,-13.289908 16.730834,-16.214841 7.475103,-4.789783 16.150884,-8.199359 24.419365,-9.596791 5.6655,-0.957514 16.57177,-0.957514 22.23727,0 21.20907,3.584485 39.53361,18.087079 47.5532,37.635017 2.29347,5.590401 3.69961,11.321836 4.08793,16.662438 0.22523,3.097744 0.63371,4.912473 1.4712,6.535957 1.40554,2.724693 1.55125,7.319337 0.41601,13.119247 -3.69769,18.89144 -18.21707,35.04984 -38.34334,42.67172 -5.55772,2.10474 -16.96215,4.55694 -16.96215,3.64725 0,-0.18395 0.83463,-0.4638 1.85472,-0.62188 1.02011,-0.15811 2.6196,-0.83434 3.55446,-1.50278 0.93484,-0.66845 3.25297,-1.66113 5.15138,-2.20598 7.89506,-2.2659 16.8799,-10.40755 21.75356,-19.71206 3.55075,-6.77894 5.05198,-12.70036 5.05141,-19.92477 -3.7e-4,-4.41879 -0.13435,-5.12736 -1.49788,-7.92072 -3.01643,-6.179572 -7.44472,-11.135475 -13.06138,-14.617608 -3.54806,-2.199668 -9.78095,-4.411832 -13.48887,-4.787433 l -2.87647,-0.291371 -4.26802,3.870051 C 105.96339,98.259782 87.258187,105.5757 71.826424,104.79612 c -2.867566,-0.14486 -6.311582,-0.59529 -7.653368,-1.00096 -1.888023,-0.57079 -2.525503,-0.60656 -2.819498,-0.15817 -0.651695,0.99397 -0.430311,11.0771 0.31805,14.48568 2.424587,11.04352 8.723737,20.76646 17.717275,27.34722 4.540223,3.3222 15.146881,8.06362 18.038447,8.06362 0.49347,0 0.8972,0.21442 0.8972,0.4765 0,0.26205 -0.0553,0.459 -0.12292,0.43764 -0.0676,-0.0213 -1.67164,-0.34072 -3.564506,-0.70968 z"
       id="path1392"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

man:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   sodipodi:docname="man-icon.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06)">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-700.29561"
     inkscape:cy="559.96269"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="fill:#000000;stroke-width:0.476758"
       d="M 82.876837,276.72443 C 48.21989,274.71322 29.861422,272.00912 13.749458,266.54233 5.5019066,263.74396 4.2423476,260.0288 5.3378746,241.7315 c 1.89833,-31.70539 9.3545544,-55.50855 20.3042014,-64.81874 7.069384,-6.0109 9.862655,-6.70646 26.770289,-6.66598 8.347482,0.0199 15.317831,0.192 15.489654,0.38225 0.171823,0.19023 0.579012,1.20369 0.904878,2.25213 7.011383,22.55906 39.690283,31.28016 60.803293,16.22673 5.76026,-4.10703 11.46707,-11.99431 12.4443,-17.19911 0.54513,-2.90338 29.13951,-2.52368 35.23768,0.46791 9.68858,4.75295 15.00204,11.97918 20.51973,27.90663 7.23724,20.89114 9.65421,56.94247 4.24794,63.36212 -2.9324,3.48205 -23.48945,8.3562 -46.21487,10.95769 -15.03369,1.72097 -58.227954,2.97669 -72.968133,2.1213 z M 97.900966,162.35269 c -15.741078,-4.17802 -31.516265,-21.8413 -35.499704,-39.74859 -0.437288,-1.9658 -1.511099,-4.96814 -2.386267,-6.67183 -3.817885,-7.4324 -4.978918,-18.342406 -2.362016,-22.195426 1.107628,-1.63082 1.107628,-1.63082 0.147876,-6.03987 -3.576537,-16.429523 0.06794,-29.91115 11.302486,-41.810493 12.412774,-13.147251 28.661745,-16.217409 49.162709,-9.289043 29.81165,10.074933 40.08273,25.585393 33.7265,50.930766 -1.24354,4.95857 -1.24354,4.95857 -0.26772,5.93359 3.13735,3.13474 2.36994,14.119476 -1.55318,22.232196 -0.88723,1.83475 -2.18505,5.37321 -2.88404,7.86323 -7.18383,25.59129 -30.40595,43.83333 -49.386604,38.79547 z"
       id="path828"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both icon files are missing size information. Depending on the user agent your page is displayed with, the results may differ and be inconsistent. Add an attribute

```
viewBox="5 30 200 250"
```

to both icon files.

Comment: Thanks it help now they are same sized.